# String value doesn't appear on Textbox when it is used with ".configure(state="disabled") in Customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, insert, customtkinter

I have a bot that is working on a game. I get some info text that shows how many monster the character killed. I used `Customtkinter` library as interface and used `CtkTextbox` for showing these values.

I create a function `go` inserting the text into the textbox. The problem is when I configure textbox with `.configure(state="disabled")` text doesn't appear after I clicked start button. But when I change `disable` with normal, text appears. But I want users not to change any text on that textbox, that's why I prefer using `disabled`.

I'm sending the basic simulation of the code here:

```
form = customtkinter.CTk()
form.title("PPO Infinite Bot")
form.geometry("400x700+1024+0")
form.resizable(False, False)


def go():
    Output2.delete("0.0", "end")
    Output2.insert(0.0, "pokemon_liste")


################################################################################################### tabs
tabview = customtkinter.CTkTabview(form)
tabview.place(x=0, y=0, width=400, height=700)

tab_1 = tabview.add("               Mining               ")
tab_2 = tabview.add("               Grinding               ")
tab_3 = tabview.add("               Fishing               ")
tabview.set("               Mining               ")

################################################################################################### textbox
Output = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(tab_1, height=240, width=400)
Output.place(x=2, y=380)
Output.configure(state="disabled")


Output2 = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(tab_2, height=240, width=400)
Output2.place(x=2, y=380)
Output2.configure(state="normal")

Output3 = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(tab_3, height=240, width=400)
Output3.place(x=2, y=380)
Output3.configure(state="disabled")



buton_start = customtkinter.CTkButton(tab_2, text="Start", command=go)
buton_start.place(x=5, y=623, width=185, height=30)




form.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Is there any different way of printing outputs from the game on the Customtkinter frames?

Comment: Change it to normal before updating, then change it back to disabled after updating.

Comment: really thanks, what a good solution :) I'm really tired of writing, thanks a lot appreciate.